# Set default python environment in pyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, environment

I am using PyCharm and each time I create a new project PyCharm propose me to create a new virtual environment and each time I switch checkbox to use existing one. How to set as a default behaviour to use existing environment?

[image]

Comment: When you first time creates the environment, you need to check the box, "Make available to all projects", as you can see in the picture that you have posted. You can read more [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html).

Comment: What if I want to change default environment time by time? For example, now I am using env1 for my project, but then I need to change my workflow and use env2 for my further projects.